# Counting the number of elements $x$ between $p$ and $p^2$ where lpf$(x(x+2))=7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Let $p > 7$ be any prime.

Let $f_7(p)$ be a function that counts the number of elements $x$ where $p < x < p^2$ and lpf$(x(x+2))=7$ where *lpf* is the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html).

It has been suggested that $f_7(p) \le  6(\left\lfloor\dfrac{p^2 - p}{7\cdot30}\right\rfloor + 1)$

I am trying to improve on this result.

Let $a = 3\left\lfloor\dfrac{p^2 - p}{30}\right\rfloor$

I am trying to show that for all $p$, $f_7(p) \le 2(\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{7}\right\rfloor + 2) \le  6(\left\lfloor\dfrac{p^2 - p}{7\cdot30}\right\rfloor + 1) $

Is my reasoning correct?  Is there a better, tighter upper bound than the one that I am proposing?

Here's my argument:

(1)  Assume that $p^2 - p = 7\cdot30y$ where $y$ is a positive integer.

(2)  The number of elements where lpf$(x(x+2))=7$ is $6y$ since:

- If lpf$(x(x+2)) > 5$, then $x \equiv 29 \pmod {30}$ or $x \equiv 11 \pmod {30}$ or $x \equiv 17 \pmod {30}$
- We know that this can only happen when $7 \mid x$ or $7 \mid (x+2)$.
- This means that there at most $6$ ways that it can occur per each sequence of $7\cdot30$ consecutive integers.

(3)  In this case, $a = 21y$ and $2(\left\lfloor\dfrac{21y}{7}\right\rfloor+2) = 6y+4$

(4) So, we have:  $f_7(p) = 6y < 6y+4 < 6y+6$

(5)  Either $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {30}$ or $p^2 \equiv 19 \pmod {30}$

(6)  From this, we know that if:

- If $210y  < p^2 - p \le 210y+30, f_7(p) \le 6y+2 < 6y + 4 < 6y+6$
- If $210y+30 < p^2 - p \le 210y+60, f_7(p) \le 6y+3 < 6y + 4 < 6y+6$
- If $210y+60  < p^2 - p \le 210y+90, f_7(p) \le 6y+4 \le 6y+4 < 6y+6$
- If $210y+90 < p^2 - p \le 210y+120, f_7(p) \le 6y+5 < 6y+6 \le 6y+6$
- If $210y+120 < p^2 - p < 210y+150, f_7(p) \le 6y+6 < 6y+6 \le 6y+6$

Note: It fails for the following case:

- If $210y+150 \le p^2 - p < 210y+210, f_7(p) \le 6y+6 < 6y+8 > 6y+6$

(7)  I believe that I have covered all possible values of $p$ so I am done.

I appreciate any suggestions, corrections, or questions.

Comment: It seems that $2\left(\lfloor a/7 \rfloor+2\right)\le 6\left(\lfloor (p^2-p)/210\rfloor+1\right)$ does not hold for some $p$ such as $p=13,29$.

Comment: Thanks very much much!  I added the point at which it fails to my question.  It works only so long as $210y \le  p^2 - p < 210y+150$